# Python prime number check

Tags: python, error-handling, primes

guys!

I have a codecademy Python course excercise in which I have to check if parameter passed is prime. My code looks like this:

```
def is_prime(x):
    for n in range(2, x-1):
        if (x < 2):
            return False
        elif(x % n == 0):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

It seems to me that I have covered all possibilities, but it constatnly displays this error:

```
Your function fails on is_prime(0). It returns None when it should return False.
```

This falls in the first if-condition as far as I can see. Can someone explain how this is possible?

Comment: you have a return in each if branch, so your loop will never go beyond the first value of n

Comment: remove else statement because for loop is running  one time only..

Comment: If you believe "This falls in the first if-condition", put a print statement in the first if and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

Hint, what numbers are inside `range(2, x-1)` when x is 0?

Answer (score 2):

This version may works.

```
def is_prime(x):
    if (x < 2): 
        return False
    for n in range(2, x-1): 
        if(x % n == 0): 
            return False
    return True
```